# Which Extension Adds: Event terms and conditions

Tags: civievent, extension

I installed an extension at some point that apparently adds a section called Event terms and conditions - I am not sure what extension that is.

It might be the GDPR extension, but I have that disabled, can someone confirm?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is GDPR - look in uk.co.vedaconsulting.gdpr/xml/CustomGroupData.xml.

Not all extensions disable their custom fields when the extension is disabled. Whether they should or not needs to be looked at on a case-by-base basis, but generally yes they do. I can see in the code this one doesn't - don't know if it's intentional.